# std::sort using inherited functor

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, std

I would like to use different strategies to sort a vector. But I can't figure out how to pass a child functor and use it in `std::sort` later on. Whenever I use abstract class for sorting strategy I end up with `cannot allocate an object of abstract type` error. Is there a way to use inherited functors as `std::sort` arguments? Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


class BaseSort{
public:
    virtual ~BaseSort() {};
    virtual bool operator()(const int& a, const int& b) = 0;
};

class Asc : public BaseSort{
public:
    bool operator()(const int& a, const int& b){
        return a < b;
    }
};

class Desc : public BaseSort{
public:
    bool operator()(const int& a, const int& b){
        return a > b;
    }
};

void print(const vector<int>& values) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < values.size(); ++i) {
        cout << values[i] << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> values = {2,1,3};
    sort(values.begin(), values.end(), Asc()); // {1,2,3}
    print(values);
    sort(values.begin(), values.end(), Desc()); // {3,2,1}
    print(values);
    Asc* asc = new Asc();
    sort(values.begin(), values.end(), *asc); // {1,2,3}
    print(values);
    BaseSort* sortStrategy = new Desc();
    sort(values.begin(), values.end(), *sortStrategy); //cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘BaseSort’
    print(values);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not related, but the comparator's function operator should be `const`. I.e. `virtual bool operator()(const int& a, const int& b) const = 0;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use [`std::ref()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref), otherwise the argument will be passed by value (causing an attempt to copy-construct an object of type `BaseSort`, which is illegal since `BaseSort` is abstract - and even if it were not, you would get *slicing*):

```
sort(values.begin(), values.end(), std::ref(*sortStrategy));
//                                 ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: `cppreference` says that `std::ref` is C++11 only - how did people deal with this issue before they had `std::ref`?

Comment: @us2012: Boost has a `boost::ref` and `boost::cref` if I remember correctly

Comment: @us2012 It simply doesn’t crop up that often, to be honest – and you can always use a manual wrapper to solve it.